# Extract 2 Different Words From a Cell Using Only: MID(), LEN(), LEFT(), RIGHT(), TRIM(), FIND(), SEARCH()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have just finished a Excel task for a job application (sadly did not pass due to being 1 mark off!).

The question which stumped me asks (paraphrased):

**In this column (B) you have the following:**

[image: 1]

**Create A forumla in another column that extratcts only "LHS" or "RHS"**
**(using only the functions listed in the title)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can complete it with the following expression: =MID(B6,SEARCH("**RHS**",B6),3)

The issue is that I have to manually change the "RHS" to "LHS" and I believe the question asks me to use only 1 formula (a one-size-fits-all if you will).

P.S - The actual question reads "The Vehicle Seat part numbers are defined as LHS or RHS. This information is shown within the Description in column .
Create a formula in column  that extracts the LHS or RHS text only."

Comment: Maybe they wanted you to find `HS` and then extract it plus the previous letter?

Comment: `=MID(A1:A10,FIND("HS",A1:A10)-1,3)` ?

Comment: And thank you @P.b for the formula, you guys were bang on!

Comment: You only needed to change a single character in your original formula, i.e. `=MID(B6,SEARCH("?HS",B6),3)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula I think works for what you are looking for. This was copied from cell B2 in the screenshot:

=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RHS",A2,1)),"RHS",""),"")&IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("LHS",A2,1)),"LHS",""),"")

[see this screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1YpH.png)